# Как отключить плагин Visual Assist X 10.7?

Tags: плагин, visual-studio

Установил плагин Visual Assist X 10.7. А как его отключить в Visual studio 2010?
Есть ли подобные плагины для F#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сервин->расширения и обновления->visual assist x удалить.

Для F# чего-либо подобного, скорее всего, нет